# how can this downcast works:(B)super.clone()?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, clone, downcast

```
class A { 

}
public class B extends A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     A m = new A();
     B n = (B)m;
}
}
```

this code can not be complied. However, in the code below, this downcast works.

```
 class A { 

}
public class B extends A implements Cloneable{

@Override
public B clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
return (B)super.clone();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
     B m = new B();
     B n = m.clone();
}
}
```

so, why this downcast works?

=============Correction============================

sorry for my fault, it should be `B n = **(B)**m;`, not `B n = m;`.
I'm very sorry. I have corrected it in the above code.

Comment: Even in first case - `B n = (B)m;` would work.

Comment: Where's `Test` coming from?

Comment: In second case there is no downcast, Assuming the Test should replace with B, Other wise it's a compilation error.

Comment: thanks to @RohitJain, and sorry for Joachim and Krushna. I have realize waht my fault is and correct in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in first case -; 
        class A {

```
       }
    public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     A m = new A();
   //  B n = m;
     B n = (B)m;
   }  
     }
```

It's work.

Comment: Well, it _compiles_. Works is another matter.

Comment: Yes it work - or rather IDE says it will work, because you type casted it, but you will still get runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

WHAT? 
You cannot cast A to B no mather what you people are saying
IF A extends B than B can be threated as insance of A and B but A cannot be instance of B.